# What is the "RECLAIMABLE" space displayed in docker system df?

Tags: docker

One can use the command [`docker system df`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180602170331/https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/)) (introduced in Docker 1.13.0) to see  docker disk usage, e.g.:

```
username@server:~$ docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE             SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              44                  28                 114.7GB             84.84GB (73%)
Containers          86                  7                  62.43GB             41.67GB (66%)
Local Volumes       2                   1                  0B                  0B
Build Cache                                                0B                  0B
```

How is the "RECLAIMABLE" displayed in `docker system df` computed? I.e., what does it represent?

The Docker [documentation on `docker system df`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180602170331/https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/)) doesn't explain it. The [Docker glossary](https://docs.docker.com/glossary/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180602171845/https://docs.docker.com/glossary/)) doesn't contain the term "RECLAIMABLE".

Comment: Probably what would be cleaned up if you ran `docker system prune`

Comment: @jordanm that is an excellent guess.  iirc 'docker system prune' does not prune volumes.  So the reclaimable space may/may not include volumes.  I dont know and am also guessing.

Comment: @emory it does if you use the `--volumes` flag.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Hi @Franck Dernoncourt!
`RECLAIMABLE` is the space consumed by "unused" images (in the meaning of no containers based on thoses images is running).
In other words and as @jordanm said, this is the total size of images you can remove without breaking anything, that is exactly why Docker will remove them if you run `docker system prune -a` or `docker image prune -a`. The `-a` tells Docker to remove all unused images, without it Docker only removes dangling (untagged) images.

You can learn more on how optimize your disk space with Docker [here](https://hackernoon.com/cleaning-up-docker-f14edd6fcf4c) and [here](https://cntnr.io/whats-eating-my-disk-docker-system-commands-explained-d778178f96f1) and of course Docker documentation for [docker image prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) and [docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/).

Comment: I have no running containers. So I would assume all the listed space to be reclaimable. Yet I have only 54% and 15% respectively reclaimable for Containers and Volumes. That seems to contradict this answer.

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer. It doesn't seem to be that at all, but rather the sum of all shared sizes that were counted more than once in the "system df" command. For example, if I have 3 containers that are based from the same 500M image, they all show a shared size of 500M and the reclaimable space will show 1G. Use the --verbose switch with the df command and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @YanickGirouard When and how can it be "reclaimed" then? Or is "reclaimable" a misnomer?

Answer (score 59):

It's worth mentioning in addition to Kerat's answer, the command you may be looking for to free up space listed as `RECLAIMABLE` is `docker system prune -a --volumes`. Volumes will not be pruned by default if you don't include the `--volumes` flag.

Comment: This freed up the space and not the accepted answer. After `docker system prune -a` I still had Reclaimable space as 54GBs. This answer freed up that space

Comment: Hmm, for podman it was enough to just run `podman image prune -a`