# How do I control the way docker determines if disk space is "reclaimable"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

In the spirit of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659233/what-is-the-reclaimable-space-displayed-in-docker-system-df), how does docker determine the 'reclaimability' of disk space used by the images and containers? An example of `docker system df` (which I have recently `prune`d):

```
>> xx:xx:xx > nope > docker >> docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              12                  0                   14.07GB             14.07GB (100%)
Containers          0                   0                   0B                  0B
Local Volumes       7                   0                   817.1kB             817.1kB (100%)
Build Cache                                                 0B                  0B
```

Can I use the Dockerfile or docker-compose.yaml to manipulate or control how this designation is applied to disk space? For example, if I wanted to continually clean out a `/mnt` or `/var/log` in a container, service, or swarm based on some criteria (number of files, or their total size) is there a way to do that?

I've RTFM'd the [v1.28 API doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.28) but I only see references to `SpaceReclaimed` in the "Responses" section, neither did the [prune documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) itself provide any clues (although I'm probably not understanding what `--filter` does).

Answer (score 0):

The response to your question is no, there is no way to control the `RECLAIMABLE` number because Docker this a field calculate by summing the amount of space used by images that are not used by any container.

You can see my answer to the question you referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51520627/7501326).